# How can I use cURL or Wget inside of a Perl program?

Tags: perl, curl, wget

I am trying to download and output to a file using [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) in a Perl script.

1) I have to pass username and password in the following below. What switch should I use?

2) When I execute Perl script, this is what I get:

```
Can't locate WWW/Curl.pm in @INC (@INC contains: f:/Perl/site/lib f:/Perl/lib .)
 at onesec.pl line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at haroldonesec.pl line 9.
```

```
use WWW::Curl;
curl http://download2.emu-lochard.com/sfo1/gru?start-time=2009-08-15+00%3A00%3A00&end-time=2009-08-15+12%3A59%3A59&time-zone=GMT&metric=laeq --data --O curllaeq.txt
```

3) How can I use [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) to do the same?

I am using the following but getting errors:

```
use LWP::Simple;
wget --user=username --password=password http://download2.emu-lochard.com/sfo1/gru?start-time=2009-08-15+00%3A00%3A00&end-time=2009-08-15+12%3A59%3A59&time-zone=GMT&metric=laeq -O laeq.txt
```

Comment: What does use LWP::Simple have to do with cmdline wget in your 3) ?

Comment: Nothing.Thought wget might require it..but ignore

Comment: You know that perl is not a shell, right? Because it looks like you're trying to write a bash script. You will need to learn the basics of Perl first before installing modules is even an issue. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html

Comment: Neel, randomly including things you think might work does not make things better, it can only make your code harder to get working and keep working.  Please see http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=78752

Comment: (I removed the duplicate question; please don't ask twice - just update the original)

Comment: You can use LWP::UserAgent->credentials if you would use LWP::Simple

Answer (score 5):

As Chris Lutz points out, you do not have [WWW::Curl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Curl) installed.

However, even if you did, it would not matter because the way you have tried to use the library seems completely unrelated to how the module should be used.

You should try reading the documentation for [WWW::Curl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Curl) and [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP::Simple).

Or, if this is all you need to do, I would use the command line utilities [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) or [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html).

Comment: It might be important to note that his errors are because he doesn't have said modules installed. But +1. And also, thanks for editing the question. I tried to but SO froze up on me.

Answer (score 1):

Not to repeat the obvious (you don't have the WWW::Curl installed) but to address the other issue, the standard accepted way to pass htaccess user/passwords is just accessing the url like this:

```
http://username:password@download2.blablabla.com/bla.file
```

Curl, wget, and every other sensible program should be able to handle this form.

Comment: http://username:password@download2.blablabla.com/bla.file
Unfortunately,this format doesnt works

Comment: curl, wget, and LWP::Simple have better ways to supply credentials.

Comment: If you pass the password on the command line, its very likely that every other user on the system can see your password by running `ps`.